# Does there exists $f\in A_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb T)$ with $||f||=r$ such that $||e^{if}||=e^{r}$?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $\mathbb Z$, the set of integers, be a group with respect to addition and its dual group is the $\mathbb T = \{z\in \mathbb C : |z|=1\}$ , one dimensional torus. Put, 
$\ell^{1}(\mathbb Z)= \{g:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb C : \sum_{m\in \mathbb Z} |g(m)|<\infty \}$, and for $g\in \ell^{1}(\mathbb Z)$, we define its Fourier transform on $\mathbb T$ as follows:

$$\hat{g}(e^{i\theta})=\sum_{m\in \mathbb Z} g(m) e^{-im\theta} \ \ (e^{i \theta }\in \mathbb T).$$
We consider the space(sub space as we have restrict to real functions) of Fourier transforms,
$$A_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb T)=\{f:\mathbb T \to \mathbb R : \exists \ g\in \ell^{1}(\mathbb Z) \text{such that} \  \hat{g}= f \}.$$
$A_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb T)$ is normed by the $\ell^{1}-$ normed on $\mathbb Z$:
$$||f||:=||g||_{\ell^{1}(\mathbb Z)}.$$
We also note that $A(\mathbb T)$ is a Banach algebra under pointwise addition and multiplication.

Fix $r\in (0, \infty)$, and let $f\in A_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb T)$ such that $||f|| \leq r$ then
$e^{if} \in A_{\mathbb R }(\mathbb T)$ and  $||e^{if}||\leq \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{||if||^{m}}{m!} \leq e^{||f||}\leq e^{r}$.

Put, $S_{r}: = \{ f\in A_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb T) \ \text {with} \ ||f||\leq r \}.$

**My question** :  Does there exists $f\in A_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb T)$ with $||f||=r$ such that $$||e^{if}||=e^{r}$$; if yes, what is $f$ ?  How to prove, $\sup \{||e^{if}||: f\in S_{r}\}= e^{r}$ ?  Any suggestion or  some specific references , concerning this, will be fine.

(Note: If we allowed complex valued function in $A_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb T)$ then there is $f\in A(\mathbb T)$ such that $||e^{if}||= e^{||f||}$; for instance, take $f(t)= -i, \ \ (t\in \mathbb T )$)

**My attempt cum guess-work**:
Given $\epsilon > 0 $, we choose a positive integer $n> 2r$, so large that
$$e^{r}\{(1+\frac{r^{2}}{n^{2}})^{n}-1\}< \frac{\epsilon}{2},$$
and
$$(1+\frac{r}{n})^{n}> e^{r}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

We choose a points $x_{1},..., x_{n}$ in $\mathbb Z$ (not 0), such that
$$x_{k+1}\not = x_{1}+x_{2}+...+x_{k} \  \ (k=1,2,...,n-1).$$

For $x\in \mathbb Z$, we define $\delta_{x}:\mathbb Z \to \{0,1\}$ such that

$$ \delta_{x}(m)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}  \ m=x,\\
0, & \text {if} \  x\not = m.
\end {cases}$$

and also we define a function $\sigma_{k}:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb R$, as follows

$$\sigma_{k}=\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{x_{k}}+\delta_{-x_{k}}) \ \ (k=1,2,..,n).$$

and using this we define, $g:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb R$ as follows
$$g(m)= \frac{r}{n}(\sigma_{1}+\sigma_{2}+...+\sigma_{n})(m) \ \ (m\in \mathbb Z).$$

We define, $f:\mathbb T \to \mathbb R$ as

$$f(e^{i\theta}):= \hat{g}(e^{i\theta})\  \ (e^{i\theta} \in \mathbb T).$$

We notice that, $||f||= ||g||_{\ell^{1}(\mathbb Z)}= r$.

*I must prove*: $||e^{if}||> e^{r}-\epsilon $; Form here I don’t know how to proceed!!!

(This idea of constructing the above function I took from the paper "Functions which operates Fourier transform, (1959)"  by H. Helson, J.-P. Kahane, Y. Katznelson, W. Rudin ; Lemma 2.1; they have proved this for space of Fourier-Steiltjes transforms on locally compact group; but I guess, proof concrete case, $A_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb T)$ must be there some where, in the literature, I really don't know ,and  may be some easy example as well possible;   )

Thanks;-)

Comment: I don't understand "let $f\in A_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb T)$ such that $\|f\| \leq r$ then
$e^{if} \in A_{\mathbb R }(\mathbb T)$". Shouldn't the last $\mathbb R$ be a $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Actually, problem is trivial for complex valued functions; which I have given the counter example there; therefor, I am interested in real valued functions only;

Comment: If $f(t)=-i, t\in \mathbb T$; Then $||f||=1$ and $||e^{if}||=e$.